# typeofimport(".json") is missing the following from type observable <>

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular7

i am having the following error:
Type 'typeof import("*.json")' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

how to resolve this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Kanji from './../../../src/db/Kanji.json';
import { KanjiData } from './../core/body/table/table_data';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetTblService {

constructor() { }
getKanji(): Observable<KanjiData[]> {
return (Kanji);
}
}
```

Comment: We need some code... but obviously typescript is expecting an observable and you're giving it something else.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? What is `Kanji`? Why does it come from a JSON file and what is its source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import * as Kanji from './../../../src/db/Kanji.json'
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...

return of(Kanji).pipe(pluck("default")) as Observable<KanjiData[]>;
```

but you need to set `"module": "esNext"` and `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in the `tsconfig.json` under `"compilerOptions"`